# HTML input button with onclick with custom onStart function not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a button with an onclick function which loads particular elements after clicking on the button.

For some reason, suddenly the button cannot be clicked and the function has now become undefined.

After running the same code on js fiddle, the correct output is executed however within the browser through xampp the code does not run

```js
function onStart() {

  //Start Button
  startBtn.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="startBtn" value="START" onclick="onStart()">
```

Comment: you probably put your script tag in a wrong place.

Comment: i have an external js file which is linked correctly to html as my code was running smoothly before this sudden event

Comment: I have used the same code in my file, however the same error appears - Any ideas?

Comment: the code snippet is running fine...

Comment: @CodingJunkie Without a reproducible example, this question is unanswerable.

Comment: this code is working will , or u can try use document.getelementbtid